# htaccess mod_rewrite QUERY_STRING

Tags: apache

I want to block access to certain urls if there's no referrer
I tried the following rule set but it isn't working

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule script.php\?do=item&id=[a-f0-9]{8}$ / [L]

apparently I have to use %{QUERY_STRING} but I don't know what to do, the apache docs are unclear

Can you help me rewrite this rule please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match a query string, you have to compare it to %{QUERY_STRING} in a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^do=file&id=[a-f0-9]{8}$ [NC]
RewriteRule script.php / [L]
```